# Overriding find in Mongoid has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

Using Mongoid 2.4.5 on Rails 3.2.1

I have a Model `Book` that `has_many :pages`.

```
class Book
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :pages
end

class Page
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :page_number
  belongs_to :book
  validates_uniqueness_of :page_number, scope: :book
end
```

I'm using nested resources so that I can get urls like `/books/4f450e7a84b93e2b44000001/pages/4f4bba1384b93ea750000003/`

What I would like to be able to do is use a url like `/books/4f450e7a84b93e2b44000001/pages/3/` to get the third page in that book.

**Now the crux of  the question:**
I want to find the page via a call like `Book.find('4f450e7a84b93e2b44000001').pages.find('3')` or like `Book.find('4f450e7a84b93e2b44000001').pages.find('4f4bba1384b93ea750000003')`

I know that I can override the `find` method in `Page` with something like

```
  class << self
    def find(*args)
      where(:page_number => args.first).first || super(args)
    end
  end
```

But that doesn't seem to have any effect on the scoped query `book.pages.find('3')` as it seems the scoped search uses a different find method.

How do I specifically override the find method used by `book.pages.find('3')`?

Comment: It doesn't work on scoped query as `book.pages` returns a criteria. You can try to patch criteria, but I have no idea about how will you limit it specifically to book<->page association.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why just do a where criteria on your pages ?

```
Book.find('4f450e7a84b93e2b44000001').pages.where( :page_number => '3')
```

You can do a scope to in your Pages

```
class Page
  scope :page_number, lambda{|num| where(:page_number => num) }
end
```

and use it like :

```
Book.find('4f450e7a84b93e2b44000001').pages.page_number('3')
```

Comment: That would work. I would like `Book.find('4f450e7a84b93e2b44000001').pages.page_number('3')` to return a Page instead of an Array, but that may be asking too much.

Comment: you need do a #first after `Book.find('4f450e7a84b93e2b44000001').pages.page_number('3').first`

Answer (score 0):

Define a to_param method on your Page model that returns the page number. This way all Rails URL helpers use that when building URLs (automatically). Then you can just use something like

```
@book.pages.where(:page_number => params[:page_id]) # page_id is actually the result of page#to_param
```

Btw. I don't know how large your books are, but it might make more sense to embed your Pages in the Book from a document-oriented database point of view. The whole relationship business is not native to MongoDB.

Comment: There are no `dynamic_finder` in Mongoid. So you can find like your propose

Comment: @shingara I've revised my example to used where instead of a dynamic finder. Mind you, the most important idea is the use of to_param.

Comment: I agree about to_params. it's why I don't downvote your answer.